# Esiste o è mai esistita la parola "augendo"?

Tags: word-choice, etymology, history, latin

Se la parola *augendo* esistesse, essa starebbe a *minuendo* come *addendo* starebbe a *sottraendo*.

Io sapevo solo di *addendo*, che indica tanto l'uno quanto l'altro dei due (o più) termini dell'addizione, ma in un libro scritto in Inglese ho trovato usata la parola *augend*, che suona troppo latina per non farmi sorgere il dubbio.

Nel Devoto-Oli non ho trovato questa parola. E nemmeno su Treccani online.

Comment: Esiste [auge](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/auge), ma proviene dall'arabo, non dal latino.

Comment: Se il Devoto-Oli e il Treccani non registrano *“augendo”, e neppure il Grande Dizionario della Lingua Italiana (http://www.gdli.it/Ricerca/Libera?q=augendo: solo all'interno di una citazione latina) e lo Zingarelli (paywall), direi che possiamo essere abbastanza tranquilli.

Comment: Inoltre la sottrazione non è commutativa (a-b ≠ b-a), mentre l'addizione sì, quindi evidentemente per quest'ultima non è stato percepito il bisogno di termini diversi per distinguere i due (o più) argomenti dell'operazione.

Comment: @DaG: Tuttavia, il [*Dizionario storico dell'italiano antico* del Tesoro della Lingua Italiana delle Origini](http://tlio.ovi.cnr.it/voci/004864.htm) registra il verbo italiano "augere".

Comment: Giusto, @Charo, ma intanto non c'è un ipotetico “augendo” come termine matematico, che se capisco bene è solo una congettura dell'OP, e poi penso che quasi ogni possibile latinismo abbia fatto una comparsa più o meno fugace in qualche testo italiano, ma non basta per dire che “esiste” come parola.